# Определение браузера способами php

Tags: php

Здрасьте всем, я мало что знаю в php, поэтому и спрашиваю. Я нашел вот эту функцию:

```
function getInfoBrowser(){
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
preg_match("/(MSIE|Opera|Firefox|Chrome|Safari|Chromium|Version)(?:\/| )([0-9.]+)/", $agent, $bInfo);
$browserInfo = array();
$browserInfo['name'] = ($bInfo[1]=="Version") ? "Safari" : $bInfo[1];
$browserInfo['version'] = $bInfo[2];     
return $browserInfo;}
```

досоздал вот так: `$browser = getInfoBrowser(); var_dump($broswer);`
,все отлично вывело

но мне надо перенаправлять пользователей старых браузеров (Chrome lt 8.0, Safari lt 5.0, Firefox lt 4.0, MS IE lt 9.0, Opera lt 8.2) на страницу OldBroswer.php при условии что например значение ['name'] = 'Chrome' а ['version'] = <8.0, как это реализовать?

Comment: Так ведь уже всё есть в данных... $browserInfo['name'] - тип браузера, $browserInfo['version'] - версия. Для сравнения нужно сделать конверсию версии в целое число и можете делать целочисленное сравнение.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Я имел в виду что-то типа такого (if($browser['name'] === 'Chrome' || $browser['version'] === <8.0)

Comment: Так в чем дело, проверяйте и перенаправляйте посредством header() - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: А если версия 47.0.2562.1? Когда пишешь floatval($browser['version']), оно выдает 47

Comment: @EugenEray, у вас действительно есть пользователи с такими древними браузерами? Кроме IE? Вероятно всего криворукие спамеры в ботах забыли юзерагенты поменять :)

Comment: @Visman Так вот я и делаю для людей застрявших в прошлом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, я подумал, что так тоже норм, так как мне не нужна супер точная система детекции.

`$browserInfo = getInfoBrowser();
$roughVersion = floatval($browserInfo['version']);
$name = $browserInfo['name'];
if(stristr($name, "Chrome") && $roughVersion <= 8){
    header("Location: OldBrowser");}
else if (stristr($name, "Firefox") && $roughVersion <= 4){
    header("Location: OldBrowser");}
else if (stristr($name, "Safari") && $roughVersion <= 5){
    header("Location: OldBrowser");}
else if (stristr($name, "MSIE") && $roughVersion <= 9){
    header("Location: OldBrowser");}
else if (stristr($name, "Opera") && $roughVersion <= 9){
    header("Location: OldBrowser");}`

Comment: Лучше один большой многострочный `if` и единственный вызов `header`

Comment: @jekaby Да спасибо, сейчас поменяю.

Answer (score 0):

Версия может принимать вид, например, 56.0.2924.87 и во float вы не переведёте. Как вариант реализовать функцию, которая сравнивает 2 строки, например true - версия больше сравниваемого значения, false - наоборот, -1 - равны :

```
function compareVersion($version, $compare) {
    $versionArr = explode('.',$version);
    $compareArr = explode('.',$compare);
    $len = count($versionArr) - count($compareArr);
    if($len >  0) {
        $compareArr = array_pad($compareArr,count($versionArr), 0 );
    }
    if($len < 0) {
        $versionArr = array_pad($versionArr,count($compareArr), 0 );
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($versionArr); $i++) {
        if((int)@$versionArr[$i] > (int)@$compareArr[$i]) {
            return true;
        } else if((int)@$versionArr[$i] < (int)@$compareArr[$i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

compareVersion($browserInfo['version'], '55.0.29955');
```

Comment: http://php.net/version_compare ?

Comment: @Ипатьев, да, спасибо, не знал о такой функции. У самого был такой костыль реализован.